# ERROR 1305 (42000): SAVEPOINT ... does not exist

Tags: mysql, savepoints

I have this SQL in my MYSQL DB (sproc with empty body so I guess no implicit commits ?).

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS doOrder;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE doOrder(IN orderUUID VARCHAR(40))
  BEGIN
    SAVEPOINT sp_doOrder;

    BEGIN
      DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK TO sp_doOrder;

      -- doing my updates and selects here...

    END;

    RELEASE SAVEPOINT sp_doOrder;
  END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

When I

```
call doOrder('some-unique-id');
```

I get: **ERROR 1305 (42000): SAVEPOINT sp_doOrder does not exist.**

I might overlook something... Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use START TRANSACTION instead of BEGIN to start a transaction in a stored procedure.

Also, you may need to move the SAVEPOINT statement to be after the DECLARE (depending upon where you put the START TRANSACTION)

> Note
>
> Within all stored programs (stored procedures and functions, triggers,
>   and events), the parser treats BEGIN [WORK] as the beginning of a
>   BEGIN ... END block. Begin a transaction in this context with START
>   TRANSACTION instead.

Cf: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html

Comment: I tried to add some syntax highlight in the answer but the edit queue is full now

Answer (score 6):

Since this is the top answer on Google when searching for "savepoint does not exist", I'll add my solution here as well.

I had a `TRUNCATE` statement within the code executed in my transaction, which caused an implicit commit and thus ended the transaction. Creating a savepoint outside of a transaction does not cause an error, it will just not be executed. This means the first time you'll notice something is wrong is when you try to release your savepoint / rollback it back.

This is the full list of statements that cause an implicit commit: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: Great hint. In my case was a `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE` changed to `DROP TABLE`. Very useful link. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This worked at the end. Thanks udog.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS doOrder;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE doOrder(IN orderUUID VARCHAR(40))
  BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK TO sp_order;

    START TRANSACTION;
    SAVEPOINT sp_order;

    -- doing my updates and selects here...

    COMMIT;

  END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

just check the engine.
"myisam" engine doesn't support transaction but the "innodb" does.
So if you are using myisam, you can not use savepoint/rollback fundamentally.